# How to validate form entry in Ruby on rails validation for specific entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I want an entry in a form to start a specific way.
I want the entry to begin with "http:abc.com/w/" and there will have to be numbers and letters after. For example "http:abc.com/w/90765g5" is fine.

How do I set up a validation so that the user has to enter "http:abc.com/w/" in the start of the field?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a regex validation, and write a custom regex to match the conditions you want:

```
validates :my_field, format: { with: /\Ahttp:abc\.com\/w\/([a-z0-9]*)\z/, 
    message: 'Please make sure it matches the right format'}
```

BTW, if  you're on a mac, I highly recommend this app to help writing regexs: https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/patterns-the-regex-app/id429449079?mt=12

Comment: i'm getting errors with the "(" and ")", is there another way to write this?